# how to make a questionnaire with a telegram bot and telepot in python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

For my research I want to use a telegram bot to fire each day at a specific moment 4 simple multiple choice questions to the personal smartphones of the 35 volunteers in my experiment. I have checke the telepot documentation and examples, but I can't construct a nice solution. The quiz example comes close, but questions and answer should be visible for my volunteers and write in a simple log file for further analyse.

This is my modified version of quiz.py

```
import sys
import time
import random
import telepot
import telepot.helper
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from telepot.namedtuple import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telepot.delegate import (
    per_chat_id, per_callback_query_origin, create_open, pave_event_space)

"""
$ python3.5 qst.py <token>
Send a chat message to the bot. It will give you 4 questions.
It handles callback query by their origins. All callback query originated from
the same chat message will be handled by the same `CallbackQueryOriginHandler`.
Timeout on questions is not needed. How to remove them!
"""

nameLogFile = 'qst_log.txt';

class QstStarter(telepot.helper.ChatHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QstStarter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_chat_message(self, msg):
        content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
        self.sender.sendMessage(
            'Are you ready for the first question?',
            reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                inline_keyboard=[[
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text='START', callback_data='start'),
                ]]
           )
        )
        self.close()  # let Qster take over

class Qster(telepot.helper.CallbackQueryOriginHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Qster, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._cnt = 0;

    def _show_next_question(self):
        qst = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4"];
        choices = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

        if self._cnt<4 :
             self.editor.editMessageText(qst[self._cnt],
              reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                inline_keyboard=[
                   list(map(lambda c: InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(c), callback_data=str(c)), choices))
                ]
              )
            )

    def on_callback_query(self, msg):
        query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')

        if query_data != 'start':
             # log this answer: Question is this tread safe!
             self._f = open(nameLogFile, 'a+');
             self._f.write(str(from_id) + ',' + str(msg["message"]["edit_date"]) + ',' + \
             repr(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(msg["message"]["edit_date"]))) + ',' + \
             str(self._cnt) + ',' + repr(msg["message"]["text"]) + ',' + repr(query_data) + '\n');
             self._f.close();
             # show this answer
             bot.sendMessage(from_id, msg["message"]["text"] + " " + query_data, parse_mode='HTML');

             self._cnt += 1

        if self._cnt<4 :
            self._show_next_question()
        else :
            self.editor.editMessageText('\nThanks', reply_markup=None);


    def on__idle(self, event):
             #self.close()


TOKEN = sys.argv[1]

bot = telepot.DelegatorBot(TOKEN, [
    pave_event_space()(
        per_chat_id(), create_open, QstStarter, timeout=3),
    pave_event_space()(
        per_callback_query_origin(), create_open, Qster, timeout=10),
])

MessageLoop(bot).run_as_thread()
print('Listening ...')

while 1:
   time.sleep(10)
```

I want to give my volunteers all the time of the world to answer the questions, but I don't know how to get ride of the event timeout's.

Second question: how to start the questionnaire sequence with a timer? I want to fire once a day at a specific moment the questionnaire to 35 volunteers.

Comment: You might get better results if you post the code you've tried so far and the specific issues it's having. And you might want to review this article:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Aron, I added my adapted version of quiz.py example.

Answer (score 1):

Denissen. 
You may call any function by scheduler like `ADScheduler` or many others.

As well more simple way used a `python-telegram-bot` module, which include  `ConversationHandler` method.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py

So you just run `entry_point` function by scheduler and get happy.

Othervice `telepot` support this action too, but more hard and dirty. is'nt it?